# Make Vim perform action when entering or exiting insert

Tags: vim

I am attempting to disable my touchpad whenever I enter "insert" mode. I believe this can be done with `map` and can be done by using a command like:

```
map i     :silent !synclient TouchpadOff=1 <i> <CR>
map <ESC> :silent !synclient TouchpadOff=0 <ESC> <CR>
```

But this obviously doesn't work because map is not going to recurse to a previous definition, rather it just ignores it. How would one go about doing this?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I typically disable my touchpad whenever my keyboard is being used at all (if it's not a Mac)...

Comment: Typically I cannot do this. I have very limited screen real-estate and expecting that I can just disable my touchpad whenever I need "to start using the keyboard" hard to define.

Comment: I don't understand the ralationship between screen real-estate and disabling your touchpad.  I'm curious what you mean.  Regardless, I'm glad you found your answer.

Comment: I use Gnome 3, and my pattern of usage requires that I use the mouse basically all the time, except in very specific situations, such as while programming. Overall its just difficult with the way gnome 3 is laid out to use just the keyboard. Not so much impossible, just harder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can setup autocommands using the events fired when insert mode is entered or left:

```
auto InsertEnter * :silent !synclient TouchpadOff=1
auto InsertLeave * :silent !synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

There may be other events you want to act upon, as well you can get a list of the known events with `:help autocmd-events`.